# Retrieve records for the last 3 months after a specific date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve records for the last 3 months after a specific date is given. So, if a date `2012-01-06` was given, I need to retrieve records from the 3 months before that date.

At the moment I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM jobsheet
WHERE js.contract = '903' 
AND js.deleted = '0' 
AND js.deleted = '0' 
AND js.jobdate >= DATE_SUB('2012-01-06', INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. No records are retrieved although there is data in the table that should be retrieved using this query.

Comment: Looks like you've copy/pasted something wrong in your query.  You don't declare the `js` alias for jobsheet and you are specifying the deleted column twice.  Could you double check that it's what you're using?

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's a late night, that's my excuse.

Comment: Your date arithmetic looks OK.

Comment: before? before, before, before. Anyway "AND js.deleted = '0' 
AND js.deleted = '0'" - you must be stoned

Comment: @Strawberry I'd been working since 5:30am and it was 12:00am when I posted it. I wish I was stoned to be honest!